# C/C++ Winsock UDP - sendto() on client causes memory leak

Tags: c++, memory, udp, winsock, memory-leaks

I am writing a network game in C++ using Winsock UDP sockets and I have a problem that every time sendto() is called, it increases memory usage in irreversible way. The strangest thing is that appears only on client, there is no problem on server even though it uses almost identical network code.

Here is a constructor of client class where the connection is created(i can't show whole code, because it's much larger and it's not open source project):

```
Client(){
nospawn = true;
status = 0;
hThread = 0;
firstrs = NULL;
lastrs = NULL;

if (WSAStartup(0x0101, &rdata) != 0) exit(WSAGetLastError());
sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (sd == INVALID_SOCKET) exit(WSAGetLastError());

gethostname(host_name, sizeof(host_name));
hp = gethostbyname(host_name);

FILE * file;
BYTE * data;

fopen("config.txt", "rb" );
data= (BYTE*)malloc (15);
fread( data, 15, 1, file );
fclose( file );
memset((void *)&server, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(8334);
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 
    = (unsigned char)(((int)data[0]-48)*100+((int)data[1]-48)*10+(int)data[2]-48);
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2
    = (unsigned char)(((int)data[4]-48)*100+((int)data[5]-48)*10+(int)data[6]-48);
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3
    = (unsigned char)(((int)data[8]-48)*100+((int)data[9]-48)*10+(int)data[10]-48);
server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4
    = (unsigned char)(((int)data[12]-48)*100+((int)data[13]-48)*10+(int)data[14]-48);

/* Clear out client struct */
memset((void *)&client, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
client.sin_family = AF_INET;
client.sin_port = htons(0);
client.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = hp->h_addr_list[0][0];
client.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = hp->h_addr_list[0][1];
client.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = hp->h_addr_list[0][2];
client.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = hp->h_addr_list[0][3];
server_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))==-1){
    closesocket(sd);
    WSACleanup();
    exit(WSAGetLastError());
};
}`
```

And the function that sends data to the server:

```
void sendCRequest(){
int sum = 0;
unsigned char c1,c2,c3,c4;

if (ludzie[0].ster[S_RIGHT]) sum+=1;
if (ludzie[0].ster[S_LEFT]) sum+=2;
if (ludzie[0].ster[S_UP]) sum+=4;
if (ludzie[0].ster[S_DOWN]) sum+=8;
if (ludzie[0].ster[S_RUN]) sum+=16;
if (ludzie[0].ster[S_ENTER]) sum+=32;
if (ludzie[0].ster[S_SHOT]) sum+=64;
if (ludzie[0].ster[S_RELOAD]) sum+=128;

if (ludzie[0].ster[S_SHOT]){
    float depth;
    GLdouble modelMatrix [16];
    GLdouble projMatrix [16];
    GLdouble dx,dy,dz;
    GLint viewport [4];

    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,modelMatrix);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,projMatrix);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,viewport);
    glReadPixels( mx, screendy*2-my, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depth );
    gluUnProject(mx,screendy*2-my,depth,modelMatrix,projMatrix,viewport,&dx,&dy,&dz);

    //x
    floatEnc(dx,&c1,&c2,&c3,&c4);
    data[16]=c1; data[17]=c2; data[18]=c3; data[19]=c4;
    //y
    floatEnc(dy,&c1,&c2,&c3,&c4);
    data[20]=c1; data[21]=c2; data[22]=c3; data[23]=c4;
    //z
    floatEnc(dz,&c1,&c2,&c3,&c4);
    data[24]=c1; data[25]=c2; data[26]=c3; data[27]=c4;
}

data[0] = 'C';
for (int i=1;i<9;i++) data[i]=auth[i-1];
data[10] = (char)sum;
data[11]=ludzie[0].ster[S_SPACE]?'1':'0';
floatEnc(ludzie[0].r,&c1,&c2,&c3,&c4);
data[12]=c1; data[13]=c2; data[14]=c3; data[15]=c4;
sendto(sd, data, RQBUFFER, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, server_length);
}
```

If there is everything except sendto(), there is no memory leak, so the rest of code is not the problem. These OpenGL calls and floatEnc(it encodes float to 4 bytes) are also not important, without sendto() everything works fine. Are there any possible fixes other than not using Winsock/UDP or destroying and creating socket again every time when memory usage is too high?

Comment: I suppose that after the `sendto` server sends something back, and client processes the data? Can that be the problem? And how large is the leak? What is the definition of `data` and `RQBUFFER`?

Comment: RQBUFFER is 32 now, data is: char data [RQBUFFER]; I tested it in situation that server was down(no responses received) and it was ignored on client - nothing changes.

Comment: When running Debug builds in a debugger, try using [Visual Leak Detector](https://vld.codeplex.com/) - it will show you what memory is being leaked, and where in your code that memory is being allocated. It should help track down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do have a memory leak in `Client()`. You call `malloc` but are not calling `free` to release the memory. I suggest using `std::vector` for this or at the very least `new` and `delete`. Other than that there are no other leaks in the code you have included in your question. I suspect you have **other code** in your program that does the same thing `Client()` does - calls to `malloc` with out calling `free` to release the memory.

As to the memory that you think is being leaked by `sendto` you should be aware that the Winsock libraries do a lot of things in user space including allocating memory. It's quite possible that the Winsock libraries are allocating memory for various buffers and keeping them around for future use.

Comment: That's right, but Client() is called only once, so even if there is a leak, how can it increase over time? I'm asking mainly about those "lot of things in user space including allocating memory" and how to avoid them...

Comment: First you should check the rest of your code to make sure _you_ are not leaking the memory. If you're careless enough to do it in one place it can happen elsewhere. Since you have no control over the internal workings of the Winsock library or third party DLL's that it loads you can't prevent it from allocating buffers it needs.

Comment: I checked everything else, also in this way: server is closed(packets go nowhere, nothing is received/processed, no other consequences excluding these caused directly just by sendto) with and without sendto() at the end - in first case memory usage increases (~1MB every 10s), in second case memory usage is constant(there are very little changes up and down, but not up to infinity). Also with sendto called only if some key is pressed - in this case: increasing when pressed, no increasing when not pressed.

Comment: Also tried this:while(1){ sendto(sd, data, RQBUFFER, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, server_length);} - same leak but 100x faster. It looks very obvious that this sendto itself is the problem.

Comment: If a Windows/Winsock function like 'sendto' leaked memory, I suspect that someone would have noticed it before, ie several decades ago.  It is beyond reasonable belief that there is any such problem now.